# Group query and top n records SQL

Tags: sql, database

If I have a table with columns `pid, sid` as primary key, and `price` and `color`.

How do I create a SQL query that can fetch the cheapest price of each `pid` (product ID) which has `color` equal to `green`?

For example I have rows :

```
(1, 1, 10, "green")
(1, 2, 8, "green")
(1, 3, 11, "green")
(2, 1, 7, "green")
(2, 2, 15, "green")
(2, 3, 22, "green")
(3, 1, 10, "red")
(1, 2, 8, "red")
(1, 3, 11, "red")
```

Then I will receive : `(1, 2, 8)->pid=1` and `(2, 1, 7)->pid=2`. No `pid=3` because its color is red.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT pid, min(Price)
from table
Where Color='green'
group by pid
```

Or if you want the whole row (and your sql platform supports ranking)...

```
select * 
from
(
 select *, ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by pid order by price) rn
 from #t
 where color='green'
) v
where rn=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    tableName a
            INNER JOIN
            (
                SELECT pid, min(price) minPrice
                FROM    tableName b
            ) c ON a.pid = c.pid AND
                    a.price = c.minprice
WHERE   a.color = 'green'
```